# Removing menus from users other than the administrator

Tags: filters, user-roles, admin-menu, dashboard, wp-link-pages

I want to remove some of the menu links from all users except the administrator. How can I do it?

Comment: You can use [Nav Menu Roles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/) plugin.

Comment: Thank you but it would be better if i could do it with the code.

Comment: You can look how is this plugin work. Its sets a `wp_get_nav_menu_items` hook. How do you suppose to distinguish the menu items, what to hide and what to show? By their posts ID or by their labels or somehow else?

Comment: I looked but I did not understand much. Could you share a code block based on roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code I was looking for, thank you.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {

global $user_ID;

if ( current_user_can( 'author' ) ) {
remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' );
remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );
remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude menu items by their labels:

```
function hide_menu_items( $items ) {
    $items_to_exclude = ['Menu Item 1', 'Menu Item 2'];
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) foreach ($items as $key => $item) if ( in_array( $item->title, $items_to_exclude ) ) unset( $items[$key] );
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'hide_menu_items', 20 );
```

Comment: Thank you. This code sets which user role.

Comment: @MehmetŞar This code assumes that only the administrator has a 'manage_options' capability, which is true by default. Check [this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) article for details.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @MehmetŞar When you check this code in production, if it would work for you, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: This code doesn't work. There is no change.

Comment: @MehmetŞar Sorry, it seems I misunderstood your question. This code is for removing menu items from front-end navigation menu, not from admin dashboard. However I leave this reply here in case if it helped someone else who would searching on how to remove items from that kind of a menu.